# JS/Jquery code which intends to highlight on the menu/navigation, the current location of the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

New to JavaScript and Jquery, I'm looking for some help/guidance as to why the following code is not functioning properly. The code intends to highlight on the menu/navigation, the current location of the user. I have multiple navigation menus on my site for stylistic purposes. Each major div has an accompanying nav menu.

Here's my code to highlight one specific navigation:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // when the window/view port is scrolled
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page   
        var theID = $(#about-me){ //div in question
        var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
        var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("#nav2 li:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active");
            } else {
                $("#nav2 li:nth-child(2) a").removeClass("active");
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need the quotes, and no need to re-make the jquery objects, and remove the '{' at the end of `var theID` line, and an additional '{' at the end:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // when the window/view port is scrolled
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(), // get the offset of the window from the top of page   
        theID = $("#about-me"), //div in question
        divPos = theID.offset().top, // get the offset of the div from the top of page
        divHeight = theID.height(); // get the height of the div in question

    if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
        $("#nav2 li:nth-child(2) a").addClass("active");
    } else {
        $("#nav2 li:nth-child(2) a").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the code is still not functioning even with your suggestions. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hard to say...can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to see what your code is doing?

Comment: Apologies, your code adjustment did work! Thank you and have a good day sir!

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it :)